# bison's reduction didn't work as expected

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, reduction

I'm trying to write a EPL parser,so I'm learning flex and bison.I try using it with following rules(SQL):

```
SELECT { cout<<"SELECT detected"<<endl;return SELECT; }
FROM { cout<<"FROM detected"<<endl;return FROM;}
[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]* { cout<<"IDENTIFIER detected"<<endl;yylval.c=yytext;
                         return IDENTIFIER; }
'$' { return DOL;}
[ \t] { cout<<"space founded:"<<int(yytext[0])<<endl; }
\n { return EOL;}
. {}
```

and bison rules are:

```
sel_stmt : {cout<<"VOID"<<endl;}
         | SELECT identifier_expr FROM identifier_expr {    cout<<"select statement founded"<<endl; }
         ;

identifier_expr : DOL IDENTIFIER {
$$=$2;
cout<<"ident_expr:"<<$$<<endl;
}
;
```

all tokens and non-terminals have type "char*"

as the input from stdin is "select $abc from $ddd"
reudction happend when lexer returned token FROM,in "identifier_expr" action ,output is 
"ident_expr:abc from"
why this happened?

Answer (score 1):

You *must* create a copy of the token string (`yytext`) if you want to use it outside of the flex action. The string pointed to by `yytext` is a temporary value, and will be modified as soon as the lexer is re-entered.

See the [bison FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Strings-are-Destroyed.html#Strings-are-Destroyed), the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/A-Note-About-yytext-And-Memory.html), or any number of SO questions (which are harder to search for because many of the questioners misdiagnose the problem).

Comment: got it.now I use a _strdup to make copy of yytext and it works as expected.thanks for your help.